# remove characters between specific characters in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need get a substring from the below example

> luvi.luci@gma

and i want to return luci. So basically i need to remove all the information before '.' and after '@'

more examples:

> pd.prd@gded

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `regexp_substr()`.  Here is an example:

```
select translate(regexp_substr(email, '[.].*@', 1, 1), 'x.@', 'x')
from (select 'luvi.luci@gma' as email from dual) x
```

Comment: is there anyway by using substr and instr and without using these keywords

Comment: @SyedAsadullahJ . . . Yes.  `regexp_substr()` is usually simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data (val) as 
(
  select null from dual union all
  select 'luvi.luci' from dual union all
  select 'luvi.luci@gma' from dual union all
  select 'pd.prd@gded' from dual
)
-- step:1 
-- find the second group (\2) within the match 
-- ie. (any word/sequence of characters (\w+) flanked by a dot and a @)
-- step:2 
-- |.   OR any other character not matched in step:1 - will be ignored
-- step:3
-- \2   for each match found while parsing, for the entire match, 
--      replace it with the second group - so the dot and the @ are dropped from the match
select val, regexp_replace (val, '(\.(\w+)@)|.', '\2') ss from data;
```